# Java Imports Programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have built an eclipse plugin, which would generate a new Java project with new classes.

Once the classes are generated, the plugin must traverse through each class and do an automatic "organize imports" action (It must be done programmatically - not by Eclipse SaveAction option).

I have tried a code segment for doing the same.

```
public void organizeImports(IProject iProj) {

    try {

        IPackageFragment[] packages = JavaCore.create(iProj)
                .getPackageFragments();
        for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
            if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {

                for (ICompilationUnit currentCompilationUnit : mypackage
                        .getCompilationUnits()) {


                    try {
                        System.out.println("CompilationUnit: " + currentCompilationUnit);
                          IEditorPart editorPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
                                .getActiveEditor();
                        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                                .getActivePage().activate(editorPart);


                        final IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI
                                .getWorkbench().getService(
                                        IHandlerService.class);

                        IHandler handler = new AbstractHandler() {
                            public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event)
                                    throws ExecutionException {
                                System.out.println("Inside execute");
                                return null;
                            }
                        };
                        handlerService
                                .activateHandler(
                                        "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.organize.imports",
                                        handler);

                        handlerService
                                .executeCommand(
                                        "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.organize.imports",
                                        null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now it makes imports successfully for few classes, while for others it throws something like this

```
MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  
This may disable some commands.!MESSAGE Conflict for 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.organize.imports':

HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.organize.imports,
handler=com.plugin.generator.wizard.AdGenaratorWizard$1@2b8e2b8e,expression=,sourcePriority=0) 

HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.organize.imports,
handler=com.plugin.generator.wizard.AdGenaratorWizard$1@25f025f0,expression=,sourcePriority=0)
```

If you try to understand what exactly happens, supposing you would like to do a manual Organize Imports using "Ctrl+Shift+O", sometimes eclipse would prompt you with a window asking for selecting import statements to choose among similar packages. (For eg: Choose either "org.eclipse.ui.commands" OR "org.eclipse.core.commands") Now thats why the above said error message occurs.

When I try to run organize imports automatically through my code, it gets into a conflict of which import to choose and returns exception.

So is there any way to handle that? Hope u understand what exactly happens.
Please suggest how I can do that.

Comment: Isn't this simply before you have multiple key bindings for `Ctrl+Shift+O`? Try unbinding the other one in *Preferences*, let's see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like you have **two** instances of `AdGenaratorWizard` set as the command handler.

Comment: thanks guys... @rlegendi I am not sure I can follow you. Unbinding the other one in Preferences in the sense? I haven't used the Ctrl+Shift+O option in preferences, if thats wat you mean...

Comment: @greg-449 there is only one handler named `handler` in my code.

Comment: The handler appears to have been created twice - there is `AdGenaratorWizard$1@2b8e2b8e` and `AdGenaratorWizard$1@25f025f0`

Comment: greg could you provide any solution for this, to create handler only once.

Comment: @uma If you go to the preferences, and type `"ctrl+shift+o"` as a filter, do you see multiple associations? If that's the case, try unbinding all of them except yours.

Comment: No I dont get any association.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was on this for about a week and finally got it working... :)

```
try {
final IWorkbenchPartSite targetSite = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService()
.getActivePart().getSite();

    if(targetSite!=null){ 
    System.out.println("TargetSite obtained");
    organizeImports(wiProject, targetSite);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} 



public void organizeImports(final IProject project, final IWorkbenchSite targetSite) throws CoreException {
Runnable job = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    OrganizeImportsAction org = new OrganizeImportsAction(targetSite);
        try {
          IJavaProject prj = null;
          if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
          prj = JavaCore.create(project);
        }

        IStructuredSelection selection = new StructuredSelection(prj);
        org.run(selection);
             } catch (CoreException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }

}

};
    this.getShell().getDisplay().syncExec(job);
}
```

Comment: :) meanwhile where wiProject can be obtained as follows,                `IProject wiProject =     ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(myProjectName);`

Comment: I was doing organize import and other proposals in one shot and facing some issues.  This gave me new idea.  +1